# Create linq-statement with dynamic components

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5

I have following fully functional method that returns a list depending on the input-parameters *(it returns everything if no valid input was found)*:

```
public List<PriceRow> GetABSPriceRows(string dekorNr, string bezeichnung, string hersteller)
{
    List<PriceRow> lstFoundPriceRows = _lstABSPriceRows; //_lstABSPriceRows is the source list

    if ((dekorNr != null) && !dekorNr.Trim().Equals(String.Empty))
        lstFoundPriceRows = lstFoundPriceRows.FindAll(p => p.Artikelnummer.Contains(dekorNr));

    if ((bezeichnung != null) && !bezeichnung.Trim().Equals(String.Empty))
        lstFoundPriceRows = lstFoundPriceRows.FindAll(p => p.Bezeichnung.Contains(bezeichnung));

    if ((hersteller != null) && !hersteller.Trim().Equals(String.Empty))
        lstFoundPriceRows = lstFoundPriceRows.FindAll(p => p.Lieferant.Contains(hersteller));

    return lstFoundPriceRows;
}
```

The three parameters can be `null` or `String.Empty` and should only be used for filtering the source-list if they are not `null` or `String.Empty`.

As I said the code works fine but I'm not happy with it ;). It seems to be too complicated. Is there any way to create only one elegant dynamic linq-statement?

Comment: Well, you can replace `((x != null) && !x.Trim().Equals(String.Empty))` with `!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(x)` for a start.

Comment: Well you could create a method to build an `Func<T, bool>` . But first thing to do would be to use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`

Comment: @user1567896 What if none of the parameter is empty .

Comment: I've edited my post. I'm using .net3.5, so I have no methos `isNullOrWhiteSpace` but I changed my code to `IsNullOrEmpty`. @Suraj: then the list is filtered with all three parameters.

Comment: @user1567896 Yes all three filters comes in action but which result to return in last your providing return `lstFoundPriceRows` which will be wrong , see only third filter result you will get , See i don't know your app. logic but what i see here i think it will give you wrong result .

Comment: @Suraj Singh: No, lstFoundPriceRows is overwritten in every step. The code works as expected. But I'm not sure that I understand what you mean.

Comment: @user1567896 let me know if i am wrong , suppose first two param contains value so your first cond will be skipped but second will be executed and `lstFoundPriceRows` will fetch value but if again third filter gets executed then your previous `lstFoundPriceRows` will be updated and now `lstFoundPriceRows` contains only items which fulfills your third condition not second. Let me know if i am missing something.

Comment: @Suraj Singh: I guess you meant the second and third param contain values in your last comment. In this case the third param will be filtered from the results of the second param and that is what is expected. I only want results that fit all params that are provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can simplify the if conditions:

```
public List<PriceRow> GetABSPriceRows(string dekorNr, string bezeichnung, string hersteller)
{
    List<PriceRow> lstFoundPriceRows = _lstABSPriceRows; //_lstABSPriceRows is the source list

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(dekorNr))
        lstFoundPriceRows = lstFoundPriceRows.FindAll(p => p.Artikelnummer.Contains(dekorNr));

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(bezeichnung))
        lstFoundPriceRows = lstFoundPriceRows.FindAll(p => p.Bezeichnung.Contains(bezeichnung));

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(hersteller))
        lstFoundPriceRows = lstFoundPriceRows.FindAll(p => p.Lieferant.Contains(hersteller));

    return lstFoundPriceRows;
}
```

Secondly you can use a where clause which does not actually perform a scan on the list (you are preforming 3 scans right now):

```
public List<PriceRow> GetABSPriceRows(string dekorNr, string bezeichnung, string hersteller)
{
    IEnumerable<PriceRow> lstFoundPriceRows = _lstABSPriceRows; //_lstABSPriceRows is the source list

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(dekorNr))
        lstFoundPriceRows = lstFoundPriceRows.Where(p => p.Artikelnummer.Contains(dekorNr));

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(bezeichnung))
        lstFoundPriceRows = lstFoundPriceRows.Where(p => p.Bezeichnung.Contains(bezeichnung));

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(hersteller))
        lstFoundPriceRows = lstFoundPriceRows.Where(p => p.Lieferant.Contains(hersteller));

    return lstFoundPriceRows.ToList();
}
```

Since now you are doing one scan anyways you can move the conditions in the `Where` predicates:

```
public List<PriceRow> GetABSPriceRows(string dekorNr, string bezeichnung, string hersteller)
{
    IEnumerable<PriceRow> lstFoundPriceRows = _lstABSPriceRows; //_lstABSPriceRows is the source list

    lstFoundPriceRows = lstFoundPriceRows.Where(p => string.IsNullOrWhitespace(dekorNr) || p.Artikelnummer.Contains(dekorNr));

    lstFoundPriceRows = lstFoundPriceRows.Where(p => string.IsNullOrWhitespace(bezeichnung) || p.Bezeichnung.Contains(bezeichnung));

    lstFoundPriceRows = lstFoundPriceRows.Where(p => string.IsNullOrWhitespace(hersteller) || p.Lieferant.Contains(hersteller));

    return lstFoundPriceRows.ToList();
}
```

Since you have no more ifs, you can combine the statements into one.

```
public List<PriceRow> GetABSPriceRows(string dekorNr, string bezeichnung, string hersteller)
{
    return _lstABSPriceRows
           .Where(p => string.IsNullOrWhitespace(dekorNr) || p.Artikelnummer.Contains(dekorNr))
           .Where(p => string.IsNullOrWhitespace(bezeichnung) || p.Bezeichnung.Contains(bezeichnung))
           .Where(p => string.IsNullOrWhitespace(hersteller) || p.Lieferant.Contains(hersteller))
           .ToList();
}
```

Finally, we can group all the `Where` predicates into one (thanks [@Kris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700932/create-linq-statement-with-dynamic-components/20701010?noredirect=1#comment31005282_20701010)):

```
public List<PriceRow> GetABSPriceRows(string dekorNr, string bezeichnung, string hersteller)
{
    return _lstABSPriceRows
           .Where(p => (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(dekorNr) || p.Artikelnummer.Contains(dekorNr)) && 
                       (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(bezeichnung) || p.Bezeichnung.Contains(bezeichnung)) &&
                       (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(hersteller) || p.Lieferant.Contains(hersteller)))
           .ToList();
}
```

You can create a simpler (and 3.5 compatible) of `IsNullOrWhitespace` by using an extension method like so:

```
public static bool IsNullOrWhitespace(this string s) 
{
   return (s == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Trim()));
}
```

And with it the expression becomes even simpler:

```
public List<PriceRow> GetABSPriceRows(string dekorNr, string bezeichnung, string hersteller)
{
    return _lstABSPriceRows
           .Where(p => (dekorNr.IsNullOrWhitespace() || p.Artikelnummer.Contains(dekorNr)) && 
                       (bezeichnung.IsNullOrWhitespace() || p.Bezeichnung.Contains(bezeichnung)) &&
                       (hersteller.IsNullOrWhitespace() || p.Lieferant.Contains(hersteller)))
           .ToList();
}
```

Comment: In that third version, why not have a single `Where` call? Also, OP should consider returning `IEnumerable<PriceRow>` so you don't have to do the `.ToList()` at the end.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten because I was trying to get there one step at a time, but you preceded me.

Comment: And in the fourth, using the `&&` operator on the conditions.

Comment: What is incorrect about `.Where(p => (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(dekorNr) || p.Artikelnummer.Contains(dekorNr))) && (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(bezeichnung) || p.Bezeichnung.Contains(bezeichnung))) && (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(hersteller || p.Lieferant.Contains(hersteller)))` ?

Comment: Ah! I thought you meand to substitute the `||` with `&&`. Thanks, I will improve it

Comment: The last code looks nice, but there is a missing `)` behind `hersteller` in the code ;). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Fixed, also added a version with a better `IsNullOrWhitespace`, simply because that's how we use it here.

Answer (score 0):

The code runs fine but is too complicated. For instance; what happens if you input a deKorNr and a hersteller? I do not know if you could fix that with one epic linq statement and make it less complicated...

A better solution would be to create three separate functions which all have their own logic. Then it would not require your original question in the first place.

Comment: Why should I create three functions? It will happen that all three parameters are passed with valid values. If I had three methods I had to call all three in a row.

Comment: If your function from the starting post is called with all three arguments filled with valid values the following will happen: Your three functions will execute but only the result of the last query will be returned... Thus you need to add a lot if/elses or modify your code to let the resultset intersect with eachother.

Comment: This is exactly what I want :). I only want the results that fit all supplied arguments. So if three arguments are provided, all arguments would be used to filter the same list.

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<PriceRow> GetABSPriceRows(string dekorNr, string bezeichnung, string hersteller)
{
  List<PriceRow> lstFoundPriceRows = _lstABSPriceRows; //_lstABSPriceRows is the source list

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(dekorNr) || !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(bezeichnung)|| !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(hersteller) )
      {  
        lstFoundPriceRows = lstFoundPriceRows.Where (p => p.Artikelnummer.Contains(dekorNr) ||         
          p.Bezeichnung.Contains(bezeichnung)||p.Lieferant.Contains(hersteller)).ToList();   
       }    

    else
    {
     // Your query without filters
    }
  }
```